# how Do Dynamic Add a new row HTML table using Jquery in onclick last column

Tags: javascript, jquery

> How To set Add Row On Click To last Column3
>   column

```
Here Is Example http://jsfiddle.net/83aqdd62/8/
```

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/83aqdd62/8/ Here Example

Comment: Please Explain .. Isn't clear

Comment: do you want to add the row, only when clicking into the last col/last row field or any field in the last col? maybe some icons behind the col would be useful - to insert a row in between any lines and not automatically trigger a new row, but just append a row on click, if needed?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xLZSx/  (+)Button Remove And Click To Comment To Add New Row....

Comment: If you want such features it is maybe best to look at some jquery plugins, [jTable](http://www.jtable.org) for example is a very feature rich one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/83aqdd62/10/)

```
<table id="sampTable">
      <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Column 1</td>
            <td>Column 2</td>
            <td>Column 3</td>

          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
         <tr>
              <td><input type="text"/></td>
              <td><input type="text"/></td>
             <td><input type="text"/></td>

         </tr>
          <tr>
              <td><input type="text"/></td>
              <td><input type="text"/></td>
              <td><input type="text"/></td>

         </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Jquery

```
$('#sampTable tr td:last-child').on("click",function(){
   addRow();
});
function addRow(){
     $sampleRow = $(' <tr> <td><input type="text"/></td><td><input type="text"/></td> <td><input type="text"/></td></tr>');
    $sampleRow.find("td:last").click(function(){
       addRow();
    });
   $('#sampTable tbody').append($sampleRow);
}
```